# How to access a variable stored in a CollectionViewCell in my CollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

Hi I've been having trouble accessing a String value that is stored inside of my CollectionViewCell to use in a segue in my CollectionViewController.

My CollectionViewController comprises of an arbitrary number of cells that have a Button, a Label and an ID. When a user presses the button I want to segue to a new ViewController and pass the ID as an argument.

I realise you can't segue from a CollectionViewCell so I need to figure out a way to get access ID of the cell whose button was just pressed in my CollectionViewController.

Below is how I create my cells:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! GroupCollectionViewCell

    if(GroupViewController.GI.getIds().count>1)
    {
        cell.groupNameLabel.text! = GroupViewController.GN.getNames()[indexPath.row].removeCharacters(from: "\"")
        cell.groupId = GroupViewController.GI.getIds()[indexPath.row]
        cell.groupName = GroupViewController.GN.getNames()[indexPath.row].removeCharacters(from: "\"")


    }
    return cell

}
```

It's worth mentioning that I have tried going down the didSelectItem atIndexPath route and ran into some problems. Namely that when I press a button the function isn't called at all.
Below is how I declared that function. Pressing buttons never prints out "test".

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("test")
}
```

I'll add my CollectionViewControllerCell's code in case that helps:

```
class GroupCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var cellButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var groupButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var groupNameLabel: UILabel!
var groupId: String = ""
var groupName: String = ""

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(self.groupId)
    print(self.groupName)

}
```

}

So if any one has a good method for achieving my goal I appreciate it a lot.
[This is a photo of my CollectionViewController with 6 items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaLYC.png)

EDIT:
I've realised that clicking on the label in my CollectionViewControllerCell does calls my didSelectItemAtPath function, but NOT the button. Is there a way to make it so both do?

Comment: You don't need to get the value from your cell. Your cell simply displays the value from your data model. Get the value you need from your data model. If you want button taps to work in a cell then I suggest your write the tap handler code in your cell class and use a delegation pattern to notify the view controller of the event

Comment: Ah yes seems like I might have been over complicating things a bit. So I've realised I can now ignore most of this question except for the very last edit. Have you got any ideas why didSelectItemAtPath returns a number only when I press the label but not the button in the CollectionViewCell and how I could get around that?

Comment: Labels don't respond to touches so, the cell itself receives the touch and calls `didSelect`. When a button is tapped it does receive the touch, so `didSelect` is not called. You either need a button tap handler in your cell, or if you don't really need a button, use an image view.

Comment: Okay thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned it but I assume you implemented the delegate and datasource in your GroupViewController.

In that case the easiest way to solve your problem is to add a closure to your cell like that:

```
final class GroupCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var cellButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet private weak var groupButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet private weak var groupNameLabel: UILabel!

    var groupId: String = ""
    var groupName: String = "" {
        didSet {
          groupNameLabel.text = groupName
        }
    }
    var cellSelected: (_ groupId: String, _ groupName: String) -> Void = { _, _ in }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        cellSelected(groupId, groupName)
    }
}
```

When creating your cell you have to set the closure like that:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! GroupCollectionViewCell
    if GI.getIds().count > 1 {
        cell.groupId = GI.getIds()[indexPath.row]
        cell.groupName = GN.getNames()[indexPath.row].removeCharacters(from: "\"")
        cell.cellSelected = { [weak self] groupId, groupName in
            self?.mySequeImplementation(toId: groupId, name: groupName) // contains you implementation of the transition
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Please note that you must add the [weak self]! Otherwise you get a retain loop (memory leak).

You do not need the didSelectItemAt method implementation than, you can even deactivate cell selection.